# How to reference pointer array to several const array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, constants

I have three set of array with different data

```
const UINT16 array1[4] = {1,2,3,4};   

const UINT16 array2[4] = {3,2,2,4};

const UINT16 array3[4] = {8,7,2,4};   //This is not PIN code, :-)

...

void example(void)
{

    UINT16 * pp;

    UINT16 data;

    pp = array1;

    data = pp[0];

    pp = array2;

    data = pp[3];

    pp = array3;

    data = pp[2];

    //and rest of code, this is snipped version of my larger code

}
```

in dspIC33, I get "warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type"

Based on impression from google search, I might do this way....

```
void example(void)
{

    const UINT16 * pp;

    pp = array1;

    pp = array2;

    pp = array3;

    //and rest of code, this is snipped version of my larger code

}
```

then would that make pp variable that store address data a fixed value? (ie in ROM memory)?

What the right way?, I perfer to keep data in const memory if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wrong in your analysis, `pp` is not `const` but the value pointed by `pp` is `const` (that is `*pp` is `const`).

```
const UINT16 * pp; // means pp is a pointer to a const UINT16 value
```

If you want pp to be const as the address pointed is const you have to write:

```
UINT16 * const pp; // means pp is a const pointer to a UINT16 value
```

If you want to have both constness of pointer and pointed value, you have to write:

```
const UINT16 * const pp; // means pp is a const pointer to a const UINT16 value.
```